# <?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?> not outputting medium size image URL

Tags: php, functions, images, post-thumbnails

I am currently trying to output post thumbnail URL with its different image sizes; to use in ssrcset.

My current code is:

```
<img class="productimage lazyload" data-src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>" />
```

But, this always outputs the full size image instead of 'medium'. Also, I have tried to use first string 'null' or post ID; but this still does not work.

Is there any way I can output post thumbnail URL with specfic image sizes I want; for srcset?

Well, it is a custom theme so I don't know if I missed something. Please let me know if there is a way to make it happen.

Comment: Is your original image smaller than the 'medium' image? If so then WP will return the 'full' image.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `the_post_thumbnail()` function. It creates the image tag, adds `srcset` for you, and supports [native lazy loading](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/14/lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/):

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', [ 'class' => 'productimage' ] );
```